# WebView Swift with request URL

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have an application that connects to a URL, do a search, and returns the data in own URL, the doubt I have is whether you can use the webview to show only the result, ie .. it connects and doing research, and the webview shows the result, it is possible? I'll post the code.

```
@IBAction func btnCon(sender: UIButton) {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Resultado") as UIViewController

    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)



    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "MY URL")


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    // Compose a query string
    let postString = "nome=\(cmdDig.text)&aliquota=19";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }


    // Here I use a println to show result in String, but its possible show webview with the search result on the website?

    }
```

Comment: I don't see any web view in your code. Is the result valid HTML? Did you _try_ handing it to a web view for display?

Comment: I try to use NSURLRequest, but after research, the browser create a new link, but accessing this link directly from the webview it returns an empty value .. the link is "www.abcfarma.org.br/wbsrv/index.php" the biggest question is whether it is possible to make a search by code, and return the result in webview. the result is valid to HTML.